# Website with static navigation

Tags: html, web

So what I basically want is this in my website :

Header will contain allot of stuff and I don't want it to load on each page. 
I want to have only 1 header, and every time someone loads a page, that head stays static and all other content loads.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: oh there are so many ways :) what languages are you using? java/c#?

Comment: well if possible I'd like to do it with Jquery ( if possible )

Comment: allright, but what server side technology are you using? or is it just static pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is basically a single page application. there are various ways to create this type of page, check out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

What you could also do (although its a not a very pretty solution) is to have an Iframe in your main page, then capture the click events on the menu options in the header, and set the iframe url using javascript.

Here is an example how to prevent the default action on a click event (what would cause the entire page to navigate in your case)
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmfZp4iFzOs&list=SP6B08BAA57B5C7810
i think this is it

Answer (score 1):

I am php developer, so I will provide my example on php.
For exmaple you can create header.inc.php,section.inc.php,footer.inc.php. These files should be included in your webpage.You are including the files which you need. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Light Soft</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <?php include "header.inc.php" ?>
        <?php include "section.inc.php" ?>
        <?php include "footer.inc.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Header still will be loaded on each page load.

Comment: You can not include if you don't want

Comment: But that misses the OP's point.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a common header placed in a [master page](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/Master_Page.html) (also refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX) as an example) which is applied to all the pages and load it in each page.
So that essentially, the code is not repeated, although the content is loaded everytime.

If you want that the content is loaded only once across all pages,that is simply not possible.
What you would want to do is create a single page web application instead, where the header (as you call it) stays and the content that changes is loaded via Ajax calls

Search more on how to build single page web apps and AJAX.

For AJAX :
1. Basic Info on it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX
2. Use it using jquery - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here's a good read on Single Page Apps -
http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)**.

**jQuery** deals with it very well. You can use

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method
- or more specific [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- or [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

There are plenty of [other jQuery functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) related to AJAX and much much to learn.